# How to set input field for aggregated object in thymleaf using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to set the input fields for an aggregated object in thymleaf using Spring Boot.
My Model is

```
public class DearHelpUsers {

    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String cnfPassword;
    private String role;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private UserAddress address;

    //setters getters
}
```

I am aggregating UserAddress class in DearHelpUsers class

```
class UserAddress{

    private String streetName;
    private String city;
    private String zipCode;
    private String state;
    private float lattitude;
    private float longitude;

    //setters and getters
}
```

My thymeleaf form is "regfuser.html"

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
     <p>Username: <input type="text" th:field="*{userName}" /></p>
        <p>Password: <input type="text" th:field="*{password}" /></p>
        <p>Confirm Password: <input type="text" th:field="*{cnfPassword}" /></p>
        <!-- other fields-->
        <p>Street: <input type="text" th:field="*{}" /></p>
        <p>City: <input type="text" th:field="*{}" /></p>
        <p>Zip: <input type="text" th:field="*{}" /></p>
        <p>State: <input type="text" th:field="*{}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My controller is

```
@Controller
public class DearHelpUsersController {

@Autowired
private DearHelpUsersRepo userRepo;

@GetMapping("/regfuser")
public String regUserForm( Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user" new DearHelpUsers());
    return "regfuser";
}
```

I have passed "**user**" object from my controller to this form.
How to set the fields for UserAddress attributes in my form?
Hope someone would help me soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
        <p>Username: <input type="text" th:field="*{userName}" /></p>
        <p>Password: <input type="text" th:field="*{password}" /></p>
        <p>Confirm Password: <input type="text" th:field="*{cnfPassword}" /></p>
        <!-- other fields-->
        <p>Street: <input type="text" th:field="*{address.streetName}" /></p>
        <p>City: <input type="text" th:field="*{address.city}" /></p>
        <p>Zip: <input type="text" th:field="*{address.zipCode}" /></p>
        <p>State: <input type="text" th:field="*{address.state}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```